# Hubble Constant, particle horizon and density (rho) of the observable universe

Tags: cosmology

Would the Hubble Constant be affected as galaxies in our observable universe pass outside our particle horizon, by reducing the density (rho) of the observable universe? I am assuming that once outside the particle horizon gravitational information is lost.

Answer (score 1):

Galaxies do not "pass outside the particle horizon". In fact the opposite is the case, as the light (and gravitational attraction) from more and more distant galaxies eventually has had the time to reach us. Once a galaxy is inside the observable Universe, it stays inside.

But the mean density of the Universe does decrease, because the volume of the Universe increases. This, in turn, affects the expansion rate since the mutual attraction of matter decreases. Note though that the effect is dominated by the accelerating expansion due to dark energy.

These interrelations (expansion rate and densities of the constituents of the Universe) are calculated by intergrating the Friedmann equation.

Comment: Good point, I think I should have referred to galaxies moving beyond our event horizon. And I do understand that the mean density would effectively go down by virtue of the expansion of the volume of our universe (which I think is the Hubble Volume) but my question is whether the gravitational "information" of the galaxies that "disappear" is also lost, thereby contributing to the loss of mean density.

Comment: @J.Oppenheim: That galaxies move beyond the _event_ horizon means that no "new" signal (light or gravity or whatever) that is emitted will be able to reach us in a finite time. But we still receive the "old" signals. Light is being constantly diminished, so that they gradually fade away. They same can be said about the gravitational information, although I'd prefer to say that their gravitational attraction gradually decreases as they move farther away.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. I presume you would be indicating that the contribution of those galaxies to the density of the universe would also fade away and I am wondering if that might not contribute to accelerating the Hubble constant (dark energy notwithstanding).

Comment: @J.Oppenheim: No, that's not the case. On such large scales, matter is extremely homogeneously distributed. If you remove a chunk of a homogeneous fluid, the density of the remaining fluid stays constant. Like if you close the door to your bedroom, the density of the air in your living room doesn't change.

Comment: Hmm… was that a bad analogy? No, I think it was decent :)

Comment: Hmm... this partially answers one of my questions if it’s true “once an object is inside the observable universe, it stays inside”.  Do you have a good reference/website that clarifies this point?

Comment: @KeithKnauber It depends a bit on your background, but I think the easiest way to appreciate this is to understand and consider a spacetime diagram. A reasonably readable paper is the classic (and on this site often-referred-to) Davis & Lineweaver 2004. You can also search for some of my other answers on this topic here and on physics.SE; I’ve discussed this several times (I’m on a phone now, so not easy for me to dig out). Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok this is a good paper thanks.  I’ve digested this before but this paper is a great summary, separating out the misconceptions piece by piece.

Comment: I *think* it helps answer my question.  If a spacecraft were to leave earth now, and continue accelerating indefinitely approaching the speed of light, then the CMB background photons (directly ahead of him) would still always be redshifted by at least a factor of 1/3 no matter how close to the speed of light he approaches.

Comment: @KeithKnauber Hmm, no, I don't see how you reach that conclusion. If you fly almost at the speed of light, then the CMB in front of you will be highly blueshifted, while those hitting you in the back will be even more redshifted. The CMB is cosmologically redshifted, but if you have a high peculiar velocity, the total shift will be the sum of those. Maybe I misunderstand you?

Comment: Ok let me ask it this way.  Consider a CMB photon that had a wavelength of 0.001mm when it was emitted 13.6B years ago.  Now it has a redshifted wavelength of 1.9mm as it hits the earth.  Now, if a spacecraft accelerated to the speed of light, the CMB photons would become blueshifted, but isn’t there a limit to the blueshift?  For example a 13.6B year old CMB photon with original wavelength of 0.001mm could *at most* be blueshifted to about 3x its original wavelength, ~0.003mm.  That is 0.001mm originally, maximally blueshifted back to ~0.003mm?

Comment: @KeithKnauber No, there's no (theoretical) limit to neither the blueshift, nor the redshift of a photon. A photon doesn't "remember" its original wavelength. But I still don't understand where you get your factor of 3×.

Comment: Ok.  Very interesting that there’s no limit.  I definitely need to study more why that is.  The factor of 3 is somewhat arbitrary.  I chose that number because the radius of the observable universe is roughly 2 or 3 times the age of the universe.  I assume that the farthest observable objects are moving away from us at 2x or 3x the speed of light.

Comment: Also I’ve read many times that you could never reach a galaxy that is receding from us at a rate faster than the speed of light.  Somehow I have to square that fact with the fact that there is no limit to the blueshift of their photons when accelerating toward them.